# C# IFormFile wrapper interface

Tags: c#, angular, inheritance, deserialization

I feel like this is a pretty easy thing to do but for some reason in my code I am getting a null value.

The front-end is Angular and the back-end is C# .NET.

I am making a post to upload formData. My problem is happening when the form is submitted and I make a POST to upload images to the blob container.

When a user uploads the photo and they submit the form the photo is converted to a base64 image. And there is one custom attribute added to the imageFile:

This is the **post data**:

```
File{
    isThumbnail: false, 
    name: "Forest-Village.jpg", 
    lastModified: 1638304459833, 
    size: 205605, 
    type: "image/jpeg", 
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Nov 30 2021 15:34:19 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}, 
    webkitRelativePath: ""
}
```

I want to use **isThumbnail** on the backend. But on the backend, the POST is only works when the type in the parameter is set to **ICollection<IFormFile>**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>> UploadPhotos([FromRoute] Guid Id, ICollection<IFormFile> files, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default){}
```

Which will then get the following in the **files parameter** of the post:

```
ContentDisposition: form-data; name="files"; filename="Forest-Village.jpg"
ContentType: "image/jpeg"
FileName: Forest-Village.jpg
Headers:{Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary}
Length: 205605
Name: "files"
```

So I am missing the **isThumbnail** attribute.

**IFormFile** interface contains these methods and attributes for reference:

```
namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents a file sent with the HttpRequest.
    public interface IFormFile
    {
        string ContentType { get; }
        string ContentDisposition { get; }
        IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
        long Length { get; }
        string Name { get; }
        string FileName { get; }
        void CopyTo(Stream target);
        Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
        Stream OpenReadStream();
    }
}
```

So I created this **IFormFileWrapper** interface and put it in the [httpPost] parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<T>>> UploadPhotos([FromRoute] Guid Id, ICollection<IFormFileWrapper> files, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default){}
```

```
public interface IFormFileWrapper : IFormFile
{ 
    bool IsThumbnail { get; }  
}
```

But it will give me **null** in the **files parameter** of the post. So it hits the post but none of the attributes are populated.

So far I have tried:

1. Putting nothing in the IFormFileWrapper interface while it inherits IFormFile
2. Putting an IFormFile attribute in the IFormFileWrapper interface along with the boolean while inheriting IFormFile
3. Making a class called FormFileWrapper which implements all attributes of IFormFileWrapper and IFormFile

And they all hit the post method but give me null.

Am I understanding inheritance wrong? Or how it is de-serializing the content from the form?

Comment: The problem might be that there is no implementation tied to the interface. I think you will have to deal with a custom binder in your case.

Comment: Yeah, I think you might be right. I just tried looking at the generic Request object and I am getting the same thing with the IFormFile.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making a custom binder I passed the isThumbnail array into the FormData javascript object. It works like a dictionary. So I can use that against the IFormFiles when I make an entity.

```
if (!!uploadedPhotos && uploadedPhotos.length > 0) {
        let thumbnailValues = uploadedPhotos.map(p => p.isThumbnail)
        let uploadedFiles = uploadedPhotos.map(p => p.file);
        let formData = new FormData();
        uploadedFiles.forEach((f, index) => {
          formData.append("files", f);
          formData.append("isthumbnail", String(thumbnailValues[index]));
        });
        newImgs$ = this._imageService.postImages(this.Id, formData);
```

so on the backend all I need to do is this:

```
var request = await Request.ReadFormAsync();
var isthumbnail = request["isthumbnail"];
```